# Azure AKS low latency infrastructure

Tags: azure, azure-aks

What would be a good infrastructure setup to ensure the minimum latency for the users in the following conditions:

- One single AKS cluster in Europe
- Users from multiple regions: US, Europe, Australia
- Latency around 50 milliseconds or less

Is there any way to use the Azure network backbone to ensure this? Any input is welcome. I know this is not the ideal setup in case of a regional failure, I just want to hear what would be the possible options to improve the latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at Azure Virtual WAN but even that will not meet your 50ms or less criteria between Australia and the AKS cluster in Europe or US to Europe.  The only way to get to those numbers that I know of would be to deploy multiple AKS clusters in multiple regions.

We publish our monthly round-trip latency figures and you can see leaving any continent is about **120-250 ms**.  That's just the pure physics of where technology is right now.  Theoretical pings traveling at the speed of light from the US to Europe alone is 40 ms and that's if you only traverse one router.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/azure-network-latency

[image]